# c++ 2D char array element initializing with const char

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, char

I am trying initialize  element of array 
 array[m][n] == char("X"); 
after printing that element i'm getting the value of it equals д (Russian d); how deal with it, and I'm not even able to initialize that element without parsing const char to char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write simply as

```
array[m][n] = 'X';
```

where `'X'` is a character literal.

Or if you like very much string literals then:)

```
array[m][n] = *"X";
```

or

```
array[m][n] = "X"[0];
```

EDIT: I am sorry. You have also to use the assignmnet operator (`=`) instead of the comparison operator (`==`)